# Restangular GET request returns 100 records only

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using a Restangular library in my angularjs application.I want to retrieve all registered user's information from rest api.Whenever I make Restangular GET request to do so it retrieves only 100 records while I have around 250+ users  for my website.I've tried using

```
Restangular.all('url').getList({limit:200,offset:0})
  .then(function (success) {
     //some code    
   });
```

This was the wayout mentioned  [here](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1322) but it isn't working for me.

Comment: didi you tried without the offset ?

Comment: check your server side - the limit might be there

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO Yes I tried without the offset it isn't working either

Comment: @AlekseyL. I don't have access to the server side code is there any way I can make it work on client side?

Comment: @ShreyasNargund may be your server itself returns only 100 records

Comment: it is not related with restangular for sure just try same request with postman to see what you get. You could also test it with $resource or $http (restangular build on this so it wont help either)...

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz Looks like you were right,I think in my case the server rest api is desinged in a way that it returns 100 records at a time,so I have to make multiple requests in order to iterate over resultset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution after some time

```
RestFullResponse.all('url').getList().then(function (success) {
   var headers = success.headers();
   var currentpage = headers['x-pager-current-page'];
   var lastpage = headers['x-pager-last-page'];
   for(currentpage; currentpage<=lastpage; currentpage++) {
     var param = {
       "page_entries": 100,
       "page":currentpage,
       "offset": (currentpage-1)*this.page_entries
     };             
     RestFullResponse.all('url').getList(param).then(function (success) {
        personList = personList.concat(success['data']);
     });
   }
});
```